# I'm a sitting Duck!

Tags: ace-of-spades

In [Ace of Spades,](http://ace-spades.com/) I've hopped in a river with hopes of crossing it, but I can't jump out because the banks are too high! How do I get out of the water without dying?

Comment: On most maps, you should be able do dig the banks down to 1 block.

Comment: @RaisingAgent When I last played (6 years ago), even with a 1 block bank, you had to crouch jump.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need to do what's referred to as a 'Crouch Jump'. The technique if fairly common in Valve games but has seen increasing use in most modern first-person shooters.

To perform a crouch jump you'll need to jump and *then* hold the crouch button while in midair.
This should allow you to jump slightly higher and get out of the river areas.